# How to disable a select box without unchecking the selected option?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a select box.

```
<select>

    <option> one </option>

    <option> two </option>

    <option> three </option>

 </select>
```

When i disable it using attr('disabled','disabled') and re-enable it again, previously selected state is not retained. Any ideas how to retain them?

Edit: Am attaching a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jazz_sylvia/xYLL4/1) here.

After disabling it, and when am appending the same select box in some other wrapper, the selected value is not retained.

Comment: Where's your JS code? Create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If you want to prevent the user from selecting it, make it `readonly`.

Comment: In Chrome and even in FF the last selected option is saved by the browser. See [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/bcS65/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to prevent the user from modifying it, make it readonly instead of disabling it:

```
$("#selectbox").attr('readonly', 'readonly')
```

UPDATE

Now that you've clarified that your question has to do with copying the `select` box, here's a solution:

```
jQuery("select").change(function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

jQuery("button").click(function () {
    jQuery("select").removeAttr("disabled");
    jQuery('.wrapper').append(jQuery('.select-wrapper:first select').clone(true).val(jQuery('.select-wrapper:first select').val()));
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/xYLL4/6/)

When you just copy the HTML, all you get are the DOM elements. Changes to input elements from user interaction is not included in the HTML. So this solution uses `.clone()` to copy the select element, and then copies the original select box's current value to the clone.

Comment: Dynamic state of input elements isn't part of the DOM, so it doesn't get copied.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to save current value in a temporary field / or in a temporary JS variable, and when you enable it, place it back.

```
var t1 = '';

//at disable
t1 = document.getElementById('select_1').value;

//at enable
document.getElementById('select_1').value = t1;
```

If you have multiple select boxes, you can save them in array:

```
var t2 = [];
```

Or, you can use a mask layer for each select box:

```
<div id="mask_select_1" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:100;
width:80px; height:60px; background:#000000;
filter:alpha(opacity=00);
-moz-opacity:0.00;
opacity: 0.00;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Set the width & height as per your visible size, and instead of DISABLE, just simple make this mask div `display:inline`. So when you want to ENABLE, make it `display:none`

You will also need to take care of div id to match the select box id for your ease...

Comment: Am having a lot of select boxes, so saving the current value in a temporary field will not be the right choice i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Save the state and set it back:

```
$('#selectId').data('state', $('#selectId').val()).prop('disabled', true);
//sowhere else in the code 
$('#selectId').prop('disabled', false).val($('#selectId').data('state'));
```

This way you don't have to take care of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

I've added a fiddle for demo,

http://jsfiddle.net/fyjGE/

```
  <select id="demo">
   <option value="1"> one </option>
   <option value="2"> two </option>
   <option value="3" selected="selected"> three </option>
  </select>
 <button id="enable_dropdown">Enable</button>
 <button id="disable_dropdown">Disable</button>
```

JS:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('body').on('click', '#disable_dropdown', function(){
      jQuery('#demo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

  jQuery('body').on('click', '#enable_dropdown', function(){
    jQuery('#demo').removeAttr('disabled');
   });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand state means- the selected option changes. The following code is working fine in my browser. But if still you have same issue then uncomment all commented lines. I hope that will work for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <select id="select">
        <option> one </option>
        <option> two </option>
        <option> three </option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" id="enable" value="Enable" />
    <input type="button" id="disable" value="Disable" />

    <script>
        //var index = 0;
        $('#enable').click(function () {
            $('select').removeAttr('disabled');
            //document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex = index;
        });

        $('#disable').click(function () {
            //index = document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex;
            $('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for your problem.

Take a look at the demo,

http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/S7CqH/

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#disable').on('click', function(){
        $('#demo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    })

  $('#enable').on('click', function(){
       $('#demo').removeAttr('disabled');
    })

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select >
    <option value="1"> one </option>

<option value="2"> two </option>

<option value="3" id="demo"> three </option>
</select>
<button id="enable">Enable</button>
<button id="disable">Disable</button>
```